# text in dropdown should be different than value

Tags: angular, checkbox, vmware-clarity

I have a dropdown in my template which is in Angular using the clarity framework. The value needs to be the agencyId, as only this is part of my object. But I want the text displayed to be the agencyName. I've tried many ways to do this, but no luck so far. Here is my latest attempt:

ts file

```
  agencyName = 'xxx';

  caregivers$: Observable<Caregiver[]> = combineLatest([this.pagination$, this.filters$]).pipe(
    switchMap(([pagination, filters]) => {
      return this.afs
        .collection<Caregiver>('caregivers', (ref) => {
          let query: any = ref;

          if(filters) {
          for (const filter of filters) {
            if (filter.property === "onboardingCompleted") {
              const value = JSON.parse(filter.value);
              query = query.where(filter.property, "==", value)
            }
            if (filter.property === 'agency.agencyId') {
              query = query.where(filter.property, 'in', filter.value)
            }

            if (this.nameFilter.value == ['xxxKjiSfMOK9WbG']) {
              this.agencyName = 'xxx';
            } else if (this.nameFilter.value == ['xxxJnVzGb5Icx08']) {
              this.agencyName = 'xxx';
            }


            console.log(this.nameFilter.value);
            console.log(this.agencyName);
          }
        }

          if (pagination.after) {
            query = query
              .orderBy('firstName', 'asc')
              .orderBy('caregiverId')
              .startAfter(
                pagination.after.firstName,
                pagination.after.caregiverId
              )
              .limit(pagination.limit);
          } else if (pagination.before) {
            query = query
              .orderBy('firstName', 'asc')
              .orderBy('caregiverId')
              .endBefore(
                pagination.before.firstName,
                pagination.before.caregiverId
              )
              .limitToLast(pagination.limit);
          } else {
            query = query.orderBy('firstName', 'asc').limit(pagination.limit);
          }
          return query;
        })
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
          tap(console.log),
          tap((caregiversArray) => {
            const caregivers = caregiversArray;
            this.updateState({ ...STATE, caregivers });
          })
        );
    })
  );
```

here is my template

```
 <ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden: false}">
        Agency
        <clr-dg-filter [clrDgFilter]="nameFilter">
          <clr-checkbox-wrapper *ngFor="let agencyId of nameFilterValues; index as i" (change)="updateNameFilter($event)">
            <input type="checkbox" name = "name" clrCheckbox required [value]="agencyId"  [checked]="nameFilter?.value?.includes(agencyId)" />
            <label>{{agencyId }} {{agencyName  }}</label>
<!--            <div *ngFor="let name of name">-->
<!--            <div>{{name.name}}</div></div>-->
          </clr-checkbox-wrapper>
        </clr-dg-filter>
      </ng-container>
```

the agencyName remains the same. I want it to change, according to what is selected in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below directive to your custom select tag:

```
[(ngModel)]="agencyName"
```

Comment: I figured out a solution and posted it. My problem now is that I have too much spacing in the filter drop-down, because I used a div. I don't know how to fix this. I tried putting the the ngIf in every other place possible, but it messes with the formatting, or shows no name at all

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem as follows:
I added this in my interface:

```
export const AgencyName = [
  {
    name: 'xxx',
    agencyId: 'xxxPPpKjiSfMOK9WbG'
  },
  {
    name: 'xxx',
    agencyId: 'xWcJnVxxzGb5Icx08'
  }
```

and I changed the template as follows:

```
 <clr-dg-column>
      <ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden: false}">
        Agency
        <clr-dg-filter [clrDgFilter]="nameFilter">
          <clr-checkbox-wrapper *ngFor="let agencyId of nameFilterValues; index as i" (change)="updateNameFilter($event)">
            <input   type="checkbox" name = "name" clrCheckbox required [value]="agencyId"  [checked]="nameFilter?.value?.includes(agencyId)"/>
           <label *ngFor="let name of name"><div class="agency-name" *ngIf="agencyId == name.agencyId">{{name.name}}</div></label>
          </clr-checkbox-wrapper>
        </clr-dg-filter>
      </ng-container>
    </clr-dg-column>
```